# How to detect UITableView scrolling down only in iOS?

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uiscrollview

Now i can detect `UITableView` Scrolling Up and Down with following code.

However i only want to fire event when scrolling down. Not including Upper Scrolling.

In `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate` with these codes

```
NSInteger currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    NSInteger maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height;

if (maximumOffset - currentOffset <= 20.0) {
        //        [self methodThatAddsDataAndReloadsTableView];
```

How to detect only for scrolling down to the bottom in `UITableView`.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare current `contentOffset` with target `contentOffset` when dragging will end. Or check `scrolling` velocity sign:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
                     withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity 
              targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    NSLog(@"%@", scrollView.contentOffset.y > targetContentOffset->y ? @"top" : @"bottom");
    NSLog(@"%@", velocity.y > 0 ? @"bottom" : @"top");
}
```